# Hesitating between "as" and "than" to oppose two words

Tags: comparisons

I am writing a letter and I am not sure about this sentence:

> Being a parent is as much of a choice *than* a responsibility.

On various translation tools, it is suggested to use "as" instead of "than" but I find its use strange in such context. Does someone know which word to use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely "as".

These are the standard comparison structures in English.

```
... less ... than ...
... as much ... as ... 
... more ... than ...
```

I'm not sure what you find strange about "as" in this context but it sounds perfectly correct to me.